# Posibility of using variables in Oracle SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle

I dont know what to search for so I dont know if question has already been answered :-)

I have an Oracle function returning an ID, I want to use this function multiple times in a SQL select statement.

Excample:

```
select 
    custname,       
    custid,
    salesorderid,
    getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid),
    qty,
    getPriceFromID(getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid)),
    getXFromID(getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid)),
    getYFromID(getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid)),
    getZFromID(getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid))
from
    tableX,
    tableY
where
    .......
```

is there any way to use a local variable so I avoid calling `getIdFromSalesOrder` again and again?
Mayby something like this?

```
id_ number(10,0);

select 
    custname,       
    custid,
    salesorderid,
    getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid) into id_,
    qty,
    getPriceFromID(id_),
    getXFromID(id_),
    getYFromID(id_),
    getZFromID(id_)
from
    tableX,
    tableY
where
    .......
```

SQL select statement will return 3-4.000 rows so in some way the variable will need to be pr. row?

Best regards
Anders

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery or CTE:

```
select custname, custid, salesorderid, id_salesorderid, qty,
       getPriceFromID(id_salesorderid),
       getXFromID(id_salesorderid),
       getYFromID(id_salesorderid),
       getZFromID(id_salesorderid)
from (select x.*, getIdFromSalesOrder(salesorderid) as id_salesorderid
      from tableX x
     ) x join
     tableY y
     on . . .;
```

Notice that I added table aliases to the query.  You should qualify all table names.  Also notice that I added in proper, explicit, `join` syntax.